Is expected that indexes on binary columns perform slower than those on bigint columns?
Running MariaDB 10.8.8
I've had to implement geo-targeting on my site.  For this each night I pull the free IP-to-country dataset from ipinfo.io.  I have a PHP script that then creates two tables, IPV4_RANGES and IPV6_RANGES.
Once populated they have 883,307 and 1,135,452 rows respectively.
I query them like so:
SELECT country FROM IPV4_RANGES
WHERE INET_ATON('170.64.224.145')
BETWEEN start AND end;

SELECT country FROM IPV6_RANGES
WHERE INET_ATON6('02a5:427e:475b:2105:b941:3d1c:e782:6941')
BETWEEN start AND end;

When I run such queries, ipv4 returns in about 0.03s, ipv6 typically takes 0.13s.  I'm trying to determine if this is expected, or if there's something I can do to bring ipv6 in line with ipv4.  (I'd expect it to be about 30% slower due to the larger table size, but not 300% slower)
Here's the table definitions:
CREATE TABLE `IPV4_RANGES`  (
  `start` bigint(4) NOT NULL,
  `end` bigint(4) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`start`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `IPV6_RANGES`  (
  `start` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `end` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`start`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

Bonus points for someone telling me what I'm doing wrong and how I could increase performance 10x on both tables 
The EXPLAIN output of both:
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | IPV4_RANGES | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 440640 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+


+------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | IPV6_RANGES | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 16      | NULL | 565858 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+


Hmm.  Still interested in an answer, but I've realised that I don't need to query end at all - in fact I dont even need to store it...  SELECT country FROM IPV6_RANGES WHERE INET_ATON6('02a5:427e:475b:2105:b941:3d1c:e782:6941') >= start ORDER BY start DESC LIMIT 0,1; ‍♂️
In theory this might give some false positives when an address that doesn't exist in any range is proposed... but I'm guessing that's unusual, and given that my query time has dropped to 0.0003s for both tables, I'm probably happy to suck it up!

(If I do keep storing end I could return it along with country and then check it in code, to confirm that there is a valid range. )

i think aloe the processing tome for ipv6 is higher as INET_ATON and alone the you get a difference

A single INET_ATON/INET6_ATON calculation (which is all it needs to perform) is insignificant and wouldn't have pointed to the difference.

where do you get that information, as ipV6 have Billions more addresses as ipv4, so the range is greater between start and end

@nbk:  "Constant expressions used by indexes are evaluated only once." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html

@BillKarwin i wrote that ipv6 chas much more ip addresses than ipv4, so even when the proce4ssing would be identical, what in doubt very much, it would take more time to process ipv6 was implemented so that we possibly never reach the end of all addresses, like ipv5v does.

IPv4 needs only INT UNSIGNED.
Finding bracketed stuff with either IP is tricky.  Here is a discussion and sample code for such:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges
(Your title is asking about BIGINT vs BINARY -- There is not much difference.  But the details of your question are really about IP searching.)
